# How to add new application to ADFS 2.0

Tags: java, single-sign-on, adfs2.0

We have few applications which use SSO login through ADFS(Active directory federation services) IDP in our organization. Now I want to add a new application to that existing SSO login with ADFS. Can someone help me with how to make this happen and what are the details require and the process to add new application to ADFS.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of articles e.g. [this](https://support.goto.com/meeting/help/adfs-v20-g2m710003).

Essentially your application is a relying party (RP) in ADFS so you need to add an RP.

ADFS 2.0 only supports SAML and WS-Federation so your application has to have a client-side stack for this.

Which protocol are you intending to use and I can help further.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! I am planning to use SAML protocol. I don't have access to the ADFS server which has been used by our organization. I need to contact the person who manages or has access to that. So can you please tell me what are the exact details I have to give him and what are the details I need to ask and get from him and the process to continue further. Thanks

Comment: That article shows the steps. Configure a SAML RP on ADFS and add the claims rules. Also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/configure/configure-saml2-settings